# #DIV/0! Excel Mac 2011 and IFERROR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to solve the `#DIV/0!` error produced when a formula yields a `"0"` result. I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac.

Here is the original formula:

```
=SUM((AX11025*1)/AV11025)
```

And here is the modified formula to eliminate the `#DIV/0` error:

```
=IFERROR((SUM(AX11025*1)/AV11025),SUM(AX425*1), 0)
```

Comment: so whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can test for the denomination value as follows

```
=IF(AV11025=0,0,SUM((AX11025*1)/AV11025))
```

Comment: plus 10 from me :-)

Answer (score 1):

No need for SUM() and IFERROR only takes two arguments not three:

```
=IFERROR(AX11025*1/AV11025,0)
```

Comment: The problem is that the formula doesn't work when IFERROR is added. I would like the cell to read "0%", and not #DIV/0.  Thanks for the formula Scott. It returns 100%, not 0%.

Comment: @user8553155 then what is the `AX425*1` part?

Comment: plus 10 from me :-)

Answer (score 1):

If denominator AV11025 is zero then first argument so avoiding divide by zero error, else second argument.

```
=IF(AV11025=0,SUM(AX425*1),(SUM(AX11025*1)/AV11025))
```

OR reading your comment to @Scott Craner answer, you could use:

```
=IF(AV11025=0,"0%",(SUM(AX11025*1)/AV11025))
```

OR if you need value for further calcs rather than string then as @A.Rashad said:

```
 =IF(AV11025=0, 0 ,(SUM(AX11025*1)/AV11025))
```

Comment: This formula:    "=IF(AV11025=0,0,(SUM(AX11025*1)/AV11025))"    works perfectly. It is much like the one that shows "0%" instead of '0." They both work well.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If the third formula is the best then please mark @A.Rashad as answer by ticking to help future users. Also, if I have helped please consider an upvote on my response. Thanks.

Comment: I am not allowed to tick up answers yet. I am relatively new here, and 4 reputation points shy of having that privilege. I also have three working formulas so it could be difficult to decide.

Comment: No problem, I am glad the formulas helped.